# Django throwing an error when I try to send a mail

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I was trying to send mail through django .This is the code I wrote

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.core.mail import send_mail

def function(request):
    send_mail('cheking',
          'cheking django is sending mail or not',
          'nithinjith40@gmail.com',
          ['ravisarath64@gmasil.com'],
          fail_silently=False)
    return render(request,'message.html')
```

But it shows this error

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/myproject/webapp/views.py", line 11, in function
    fail_silently=False)
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 60, in send_mail
    return mail.send()
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/expert/project _jango/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 70, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/smtplib.py", line 729, in login
    raise last_exceptio
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials d65sm27731624pfa.159 - gsmtp')
```

How can I  solve this error? 'I enable **Less secure app access**' then showing the same error
Feel free to ask details about the code lines that I've omitted,in the comment section

Comment: show settings of email

Comment: show your settings

Answer (score 0):

This is not a django error, it looks like a gmail issue. Be sure you can read and send mails via gmail web and follow [gmail troubleshooting steps](https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials). I would, however, recommend you to move to [App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833).